# Why cannot I return my response list from retrofit as a return type instead I need to have a callback listener from activity and then pass the data

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, retrofit2

Here is my rest controller method

fun getPosts() : ArrayList {

```
    val result = ArrayList<Post>()

    val retrofit = RetrofitClient.retrofitInstance
    val service = retrofit?.create(ApiService::class.java)
    val call = service?.getPosts()

    call?.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Post>> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Post>>, t: Throwable) {

        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Post>>, response: Response<List<Post>>) {

            println(response.body()?.size)
            if(response.isSuccessful && response.body()!= null) {

                val posts = response.body()
                listener.onRestDataReceived(posts!!)
                    result.addAll(posts!!)

            }
        }

    })
    return result
}
```

When I try to access the data from return type I get the empty array list but if I use a interface callback method and pass the data through the interface and implement the interface in  my activity I can access the data

Comment: Because that Retrofit operation is asynchronous. Your code does not pause and wait at the `enqueue()` call, but continues immediately to the `return`, at which point, the list is still empty.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The `enqueue(Callback<T> callback)` method your are calling is asynchronous, so the actual result of `enqueue(Callback<T> callback)` you get in `callback` methods. In your `getPosts()` method after calling `call?.enqueue` your code execution immediately passes to `return result;` statement and that's why your are getting an empty array.

Comment: Yes when I did a debug the code immediately returned the list and then I used interface listener , But i wanted to know why that happened , this was a nice explanation, Thank You :)